# what is the basic role of Ienumerable object in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I dont know anything about Ienumerable object.what is the role of Ienumarble interface in .net ? Please tell me whether it is in built? Is every class in .net automatically implements the Ienumarable interface ? why there is need to implement the ienumerable interface? what are the methods it contains & what roles they plays. Please explain in detail.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? MSDN? Google? If none of that helped, please be specific as to what you don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28VS.71%29.aspx) exposes an enumerator, which allows support of a simple iteration over a **non-generic** collection.

It basically allows foreach loops over a collection, i.e.:

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
{
   // Do something
}
```

The only method you need implement to use IEnumable in your own class is `GetEnumerator()` which returns `IEnumerator`.

The IEnumerator you return must be a class that implements the following methods:

```
void Reset();
object Current();
bool MoveNext();
```

A basic example of an IEnumerator class, taken from [here](http://codebetter.com/blogs/david.hayden/archive/2005/03/08/59419.aspx):

```
private class ClassEnumerator : IEnumerator
{
    private ClassList _classList;
    private int _index;

    public ClassEnumerator(ClassList classList)
    {
        _classList = classList;
        _index = -1;
    }

    #region IEnumerator Members

    public void Reset()
    {
        _index = -1;
    }

    public object Current
    {
        get
        {
            return _classList._students[_index];
        }
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        _index++;
        if (_index >= _classList._students.Count)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: **over a non-generic** collection.

Comment: @Lukas Šalkauskas, please elaborate as the MSDN documentation simply states "collection" - not "non-generic collection".

Comment: @Sohnee - IEnumerable is for non-generic types. IEnumable<T> would be for generic types.